# eclipseでデバッグ実行してカバレッジ取得

Tags: java, eclipse

eclipseでeclemmaを使用してガバレッジを取得しています。
JUnitで実行した場合はカバレッジを取得出来るのですが、
JUnitのデバッグモードで動かすとカバレッジが取得出来ません。

デバッグモードだとカバレッジは取得出来ない仕様なのでしょうか。

eclipseのバージョンは4.22です。

Comment: https://qiita.com/poad1010/items/54d2685c3ad4a5f99c9a に手順があります。

Comment: ありがとうございます！出来ました！！助かりました！